# Using glob, match directory pattern and return highest according to order

Tags: python, glob

I have a directory

```
C:\Chrome\
  |-31.0.1649.39
  |-31.0.1650.38
  |-31.0.1650.39
  |-31.0.1651.37
  |-31.1.1650.38
  |-32.0.1700.4
  |-33.0.1750.154
  |-34.0.1847.137
```

Given the base version, I do

```
newest = glob.glob(r"C:\Program Files\Chrome\{0}.*.*.*\chrome.exe".format(base_version))[-1]
```

Does anyone know a better way to do this?  My hesitation is towards the wildcard, I tried matching only digits [0-9] but I couldn't get to work and thought if this works and the directories would always be named in this convention with no other directories present. Should I use `re`?  Another concern is if glob will always return an ordered list where the highest version is the last element.  Would this be different on another system?

Comment: I don't quite understand, given a known major number, you want the latest revision?

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, exactly. So say, for example, base_version is already set to 31, I'd expect newest to be set to '31.1.1650.38'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to convert the version number to a list of ints to get it to sort correctly. You could enumerate the globbed result and build a second list that contains 2-tuples of (version_list, file_path) and sort that:

```
chromedirs = []
# list chrome directories
for chromedir in glob.glob(r"C:\Program Files\Chrome\{0}.*.*.*".format(base_version):
    try:
        # decimalized version list for sorting
        chrome_ver = [int(d) for d in os.path.basename(chromedir).split('.')]
        chromedirs.append((chrome_ver, chromedir))
    except ValueError:
        continue
if chromedirs:
    # sort the result and grab the last
    chrome = os.path.join(chromedirs.sort()[-1][1], 'chrome.exe')
    print chrome
```

Comment: Upvoted.  Why would we have to enumerate versus what @shavenwarthog suggested of sorting textually?

Comment: @d_rez90, textually 10 is less than 9. Numerically its greater than. This is a common problem when comparing version strings. It works fine up til release 9 then goes sideways when the versions hit multiple digits.

Answer (score 1):

`glob` returns files in arbitrary order, you'll have to sort the output.

If you know the filenames will *always* have the same number of digits, you can just sort textually, which is simpler:

```
newest = sorted( glob.glob(r"{0}.*\chrome.exe".format(base_version))[-1]
```

Comment: Upvoted. Can you elaborate on 'an arbitrary order'?  I read that it returns depending on some registry entry.  I'd guess that it would return the current order of of the files depending on the way it is ordered if you were to just navigate to the folder via Windows Explorer.

Also, regarding same number of digits: The example shows they do not have the same number of digits.  It does have the same number of fields separated by '.' though, similar to an IP address.

Comment: `glob` returns files in an order that makes sense to the file system, but not necessarily to us. Thus, we generally have to sort it. If we don't care about the order, just take the list as it comes.

Comment: If you know the number of digits is the same, then the code is simpler.  In your case this doesn't apply, thus @tdelaney's solution is better.  See https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#The_Old_Way_Using_Decorate-Sort-Undecorate